# Function return variables, issue with memory

Tags: javascript, memory

I'd like to know how to set a variable to null when it's using in a return function...

My function :

```js
function myFct() {
  var test = '0';
  return test;
}
console.log(myFct());
```

Issue : `test` is not set to null after the return statement... I get an issue with the memory.

Comment: This isn't clear - the variable `test` doesn't **exist** after the function returns.

Comment: it is clear. there is only overuse of variable definition

Comment: null is different  than '0'

Comment: You do not have memory issue with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` is local variable and it will be destroyed after myFct returns. You do not return `test` but you return memory address which has value is a string of 0 pointed by `test`.

When executing this line `console.log(myFct());` myFct will return that memory address and you print out that memory address value to console but you do not assign any reference to that memory address so it becomes eligible for garbage collection right after this line `console.log(myFct());`. It means your code is safe, you don't need to set anything to null

Answer (score -2):

just return `null;` or use `var test = null;`

`null` is a special value